# spacing grid item in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

> I want to space grid item in recyclerview it works for now for all sides(top,bottom..etc)
>
> I want to apply space only from the top, the right side can anyone help me to change existing code.

```
public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int spanCount;
    private int spacing;
    private boolean includeEdge;

    public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
        this.spanCount = spanCount;
        this.spacing = spacing;
        this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
        int column = position % spanCount; // item column

        if (includeEdge) {
            outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

            if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
                outRect.top = spacing;
            }
            outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
        } else {
            outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
            outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
            if (position >= spanCount) {
                outRect.top = spacing; // item top
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> below is Adapter's item xml.
>
> in this xml i have given margin according to my need but it doesnot affect the layout.
>
> although, i have commented 2 lines of code(from else part) from decoration class and its working now.`/*if (position >= spanCount) {
>                   outRect.top = spacing; // item top
>               }*/`

**xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_120dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_120dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:elevation="@dimen/margin_2"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_2"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_2"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/category_item"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_60dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_60dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/home" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cat_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_5dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: If I correctly understood what you want to do, you can just go into your items' layout and specify a margin-top and margin-right to the top parent layout, so every item will have the same margin

Comment: i have tried this ..but parent cardview only apply margint to bottom

Comment: sorry I am missing your point here. What do you mean by "parent cardview only apply margin to bottom"? Cna you please add some code for that?

Comment: add your xml code

Comment: @GregorioPalamà  xml updated.

Comment: add more margin to cardview

Comment: if you use the margin in the layout, the item decoration is no longer needed, although you want to add some more decorations

Comment: @GregorioPalamà i know when apply in layout then decoration no need .. i applied when decoration wasn't working...